# Cannot get bouncycaste cipher instance

Tags: java, encryption

I cannot seem to get a bouncy castle Cipher to load an instance.

I printed out all the algorithms and all the providers, and part of the list is as follows:

```
RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding : [SunMSCAPI version 1.7]
RSA/ISO9796-1        : [BC version 1.46]
RSA/OAEP             : [BC version 1.46]
RSA/PKCS1            : [BC version 1.46]
```

According to examples I have seen, this should work

```
    try
    {

        Cipher cipherb = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/PKCS1", "BC");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        ...
    }       
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ;
    }
```

But I get an exception on the the call to Cipher.getInstance

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: 
   Invalid transformation format:RSA/PKCS1
```

However, RSA/PKCS1 is in the list.  The only cipher I can get an instance of is the Sun one RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding, which is not compatible with where my data to be decrypted is coming from.  And I can't figure out why this does not work.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think there is a difference between `RSA/PKCS1` and `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter for `Cipher.getInstance(..)`is the transformation that have the form:

```
"algorithm/mode/padding" or
"algorithm"
```

According to [bouncycastle's specification](https://bouncycastle.org/specifications.html) RSA + PKCS1 have the form: `"RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding"` in BouncyCastle

This is as Maarten hinted in his comment, the same as what you get with the SUN provider using `"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"`

Comment: Thanks, I had not seen that nugget in the bouncycastle spec, and was (foolishly I guess) relying on what was reported.  Also I don't know that there is a difference in the encoding, but I am having an issue with the decoding and it seems quicker to try a few variations, rather than to read code to figure out exactly what it is doing.